# How to Automatically Map TPH Derived Classes in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, discriminator

By default, EF6 would map a base abstract class and it's derived classes for Table Per Hierarchy (TPH).

EF Core no longer follows this logic and requires derived classes to be opted in. The documentation states:

> By convention, types that are exposed in DbSet properties on your
> context are included in the model as entities. Entity types that are
> specified in the OnModelCreating method are also included, as are any
> types that are found by recursively exploring the navigation
> properties of other discovered entity types.

Using this approach is not too hard to follow if you have a few sub-types as you can just add them as DbSets or add a HasDiscriminator().HasValue() for each sub-type with mapping as below:

```
builder.HasDiscriminator()
    .HasValue<CommaSymbolRule>("CommaSymbolRule")
    .HasValue<DashSymbolRule>("DashSymbolRule")
    .HasValue<IsNumericSymbolRule>("IsNumericSymbolRule")
    .HasValue<IsPunctuationSymbolRule>("IsPunctuationSymbolRule")
    .HasValue<PeriodSymbolRule>("PeriodSymbolRule")
```

In some circumstances this is a sub-optimal as you may have many derived classes. In my case, I have a rules engine and do not want to have map each rule individually.

Is there a way to automatically map the sub-types of a base class in an EF Core Table Per Hierarchy scenario without having to manually add them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought there may be a way to do this in EF Core, but found that there was not one.

I discussed with the EF team why automatic opt-in is no longer the default and they gave concerns about the stability of "assembly scanning solutions" which are probably very valid. They did not seem too interested in adding a new feature along those lines at this moment.

Here is what I came up with instead. It puts the assembly scanning in the mapping code but seems to work.

First, I created an extension method to get the derived classes (which optionally can ignore particular types by name):

```
public static Type[] GetDerivedClasses(this Type type, string[] ignoreTypeNames = null) 
{
    ignoreTypeNames = ignoreTypeNames ?? new string[0];

    return Assembly.GetAssembly(type)
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where
                    (
                        t => t.IsSubclassOf(type) &&
                        (!ignoreTypeNames?.Any(t.Name.Contains) ?? false)
                    )
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
                    .ToArray();
}
```

Then use code similar to this for the base class in the EF Core mapping, switching out your type (ie: "SymbolRule" in this code):

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SymbolRule> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("SymbolRule");       // my example table
    builder.HasKey(t => t.SymbolRuleId); // my example key


    foreach (var type in typeof(SymbolRule).GetDerivedClasses())
    {
        builder.HasDiscriminator()
               .HasValue(type, type.Name);
    }
}
```

The foreach gets the derived classes from the base class and loops through them and adds a discriminator type for each.