# In Entity Framework Core, is it possible to map this type of relationship?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database table that stores user entered localization strings for many other tables in the database.

| PK | TableName | RecordID | Field | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TableA | 1 | Name |  |
| 2 | TableA | 1 | Category |  |
| 3 | TableB | 1 | Make |  |
| 4 | TableB | 1 | Model |  |

I don't know if there is a term for this type of table so sorry for the vague title. When querying for this data in SQL we would simply join on TableName and RecordID.

How would I go about mapping this in Entity Framework? Is a navigation property possible with a table like this?

I was hoping that something could be done in OnModelCreating to configure navigation properties on the base entity to only include records where `TableName == "Table_"`. If possible I'd like to avoid having to add a Where clause in an .Include statement every time a record is queried.

```
public class TableA
{
  // This should only include PK 1-2
  public List<LocalizedString> LocalizedStrings { get; set; } 
}

public class TableB
{
  // This should only include PK 3-4
  public List<LocalizedString> LocalizedStrings { get; set; }
}
```

The only possible solution I can think of is to try using TPH inheritance. With the TableName as the discriminator I believe I would need to create a class for every type. TableALocalizedString, TableBLocalizedString, etc. If possible I'd like to avoid that, this table references a lot of other tables.

Comment: Does this answer help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778874/how-to-automatically-map-tph-derived-classes-in-ef-core/65778875#65778875

Comment: @WillC, if I have to go the route of creating new classes for every entity then that answer will be very useful, thanks. If possible I'd like to avoid having separate class definitions though.